# I am an Indian. Can i go out from airport during my 20+ hours layover in London and visit places?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, layovers

I am an Indian working in Thailand. I have to visit Spain in Feb 2017 and on the way, I may have a layover of around 15- 24+ hours in London. Am I allowed to pass emigration and go out in city to visit places or do  I need a Transit visa for my visit.

Answer (score 3):

If you go through the UK's ["check if you need a visa" tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) you will find that you need a visa whether or not you plan to leave the airport, unless you meet one of the exceptions (such as if you hold a long-term "category D" visa for Spain, not an ordinary "category C" short-term visit visa).

To leave the airport (and pass through UK immigration), you'll need a [Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa). If you do not need or want to pass through UK immigration (even to recheck luggage because you have booked two separate tickets), you can apply for a [Direct Airside Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa).